# how to implement two aggregate functions on the same column mysql

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT max(sum(`orderquantity`)), `medicinename` 
FROM `orerdetails` 
WHERE `OID`=
   (
       SELECT `OrderID` 
       FROM `order` 
       where `VID` = 5 AND `OrerResponse` = 1
   )
GROUP BY `medicinename`
```

i want to get the max of the result(sum of the order quantity) but it gives error any soultion to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `Max()` here. Instead sort your recordset by that `Sum('orderquantity')` descending, and take the first record returned:

```
SELECT sum(`orderquantity`) as sumoforderqty, `medicinename` 
FROM `orerdetails` 
WHERE `OID`=
   (
       SELECT `OrderID` 
       FROM `order` 
       where `VID` = 5 AND `OrerResponse` = 1
   )
GROUP BY `medicinename`
ORDER BY sumoforderqty DESC
LIMIT 1
```